# Apple Mach-O : Undefined symbols for architecture i386: in PhoneGap Cordova 2.9.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am new in phonegap app development in iOS. After adding `CordovaLib.xcodeproj` in my xcode project, I made architecture changes in buildsettings as [suggested here](http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/xcode-5-1-and-cordova-ios/). `Other linker flag` is `-all_load` and `-Obj-C` When I build the project, I get `Apple Mach-O linker` errors described below. I have not mentioned i386 anywhere in my build settings. How do I negate this error?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:handleOpenURL:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_LoginPlugin in LoginPlugin.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPluginResult", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LoginPlugin.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_LoginPlugin in LoginPlugin.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Please update if you find any solutions.

Comment: Target->Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries(make sure the necessary libs were added- if you used 3rd party libs make sure you add that ) and Compile sources( all your m files were imported).

Comment: @JoelJeske I did not find any solution so far. I started working in objective C (natively). Will look for the solution later.

Comment: @MohammedImranN I checked and made sure that all .m files are there in Compile sources and libraries are linked. But still get this error. Its hard to say if this is a phonegap issue or the old 3rd party library issue but looking at the error, I don't see its a library issue. Will check it later.

Comment: I have same issue. I use 3rd party lib.

Comment: I ended up starting from a fresh project and copying over some config and plugins and all is well. Something must had happened within my project build/link settings.